# Can running nodes pull images from non-working ones?

Tags: kubernetes

For example if we have k8s cluster consisting 3 nodes and this cluster dont have access to dockerhub, and one of the nodes have running pod which use image called A1:latest,and this node crushes, will other nodes be able to get this image from failed node and restart pod?

If k8s cant do this, are there any ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

K8s worker nodes in kubernetes cluster depends on [container runtime](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/) which will be running on it.  Once pod is scheduled on particular worker node, its container runtime which will pull image from the image repository.   If node gets crashed, then if its a deployment definition then the pod will get scheduled to another node.  The image gets pulled based on the information provided in "image:" tag.  More details on image, image pull policy are in [K8s documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/).

Its better to push images to private repo and use it.

If its needs to be done manually done without using private image repository then image needs to be saved as a tar file and copy the tar file to all worker nodes.  This needs to be loaded manually using CRI tools using load command.

Save image to tar file

```
docker save A1:latest | gzip > A1:latest.tar.gz
```

Copy the tar to all worker nodes.

Load tar file to runtime

```
docker load < A1:latest.tar.gz
```